# How do I keep a NAME when I disable a button with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have code similar to this:

```
<INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="VAR1" VALUE="X" OnClick="
  this.disabled=true;
  this.value='Submitting...';
  this.form.submit();">
```

The problem is that I need that name in the handler but it seems that disabling the button also disables the name.  I tried adding 'this.name="VAR1";' but that didn't work.  Does anyone know how to pass the information that a specific button was pressed?  It doesn't have to be a name.  Alternative methods welcome.

Comment: Disabling any field will prevent it being submitted. You could maybe not disable it and overwrite the onclick to do something else/nothing. Or maybe don't rely on that being set. Or maybe set a hidden element with the name/value.

Comment: you could use a timeout for disabeling.

Comment: Another option would be to set the buttons css to `display:none` effectively hiding the button but it would still be submitted. You could also show some other text in place where the button used to be.

Comment: If you want to pass info, why would you disable the button?

Comment: @Sagar presumably so the user can't modify it, hence "disabling" it.  It isn't obvious that disabled controls aren't included in form data.

Comment: I disable it to prevent double clicking.

Comment: @amy is correct, sort of.  It's a submit button so modifying it isn't the issue.  My actual code involves two buttons labelled "Update" and "Save draft".  If they press "Update" then the form is submitted and a database is updated.  I want to prevent the user from going back and submitting it again.  However, my simplistic attempt above, while preventing the duplicate update, does not send the the named variables ("UPDATE" and "DRAFT" in my case) to the form handler.  As a result I don't know whether they are submitting the form or saving a draft.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that you can do. Just prevent default event on keypress. This will allow you to access the attributes. You can also do some styling to it by accessing it's data ref.

```js
(function(){
  
  // Attach DOM
  var debug = document.getElementById('debug');
  var elm = document.querySelectorAll('[data-disabled="false"]');
  
  for (var i = 0; i < elm.length; i++) {
  
    elm[i].addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    
      // Disable default event
      evt.preventDefault();
      
      // Disabled State
      evt.target.dataset.disabled = true;
      evt.target.value = 'Submitting...';
       
      // Log Information to DOM
      debug.innerHTML = this.getAttribute('name') + ' is still accessible, but input is disabled by disabling click so that the user doesn\nt submit anything, but the attributes can still be read.';
      
      // Artificial request, completes in 2 seconds
      setTimeout(function() {
        evt.target.value = 'Done!';
        evt.target.dataset.disabled = false;
      }, 2000);
      
    });
    
  }
})();
```

```css
input {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
input[data-disabled="true"]{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="superInput" data-disabled="false" value="Submit" />
<div id="debug"></div>
```

Comment: I don't understand this answer.  It doesn't even seem to have anything to do with submit type input.  It also looks like it presents a disabled input but what I want is an active input (submit) that is disabled as soon as it is clicked.

Comment: D'Arcy it has been adapted to your request, please check it now.